# regexp get pathname even if you don't know some part of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```js
var test = 'filename.hash12345678.js';
```

All i know at that stage is `filename` itself. i don't know hash. Now, I need to do axios call, but because i don't know what comes after the filename, i can't put the actual path in the axios. how Can I get the whole path of the file ?

```js
axios.get(`${filename}.whattoputhere`);
```

How can I achieve this with regex ?

Comment: Split by `.` and get 2nd part

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have the `test` variable at all. All I know is filename.

Comment: So you want get a file, where you don't know its complete filename, but only part of it? This cannot be done, unless the server supports this (ie can search for files with that partial name)